# Adding a permanent SSH agent forwarding in Bash shell WSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I'm trying to add a mykeypair.pem permanently to my ~/.ssh/config file in window bash. 
I have given the config file in ~/.ssh/config  cmod 600 permissions.
The location of mykeypair.pem is

```
/mnt/c/Users/xxx/AWS/mykeypair.pem
```

I added

```
IdentityFile /mnt/c/Users/xxx/AWS/mykeypair.pem
```

to the config file in ~/.ssh/config but getting the message

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

What am I doing wrong?

merci A

Answer (score 2):

1. create file

   `$ nano ~/.ssh/config`
2. create a directory `~/.ec2` in the WSL and copy the **mykeypair.pem** there
3. change permissions `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config`
4. insert into ~/.ssh/config

   ```
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykeypair
   ```
5. use `$ ssh -A  ubuntu@public DNS`

Answer (score 0):

The mykeypair.pem file needs read only permissions. On Windows this is actually a pain to setup correctly.

The following are the commands that I must run to set the permissions correctly on a Windows system. If you skip any steps it wont work. SSH-KEYGEN is a good tool to verify that you have the correct permissions set (ssh-keygen -y -f mykeypair.pem > mykeypair.pub.openssh)

```
REM Disable inheritance on mykeypair.pem
icacls mykeypair.pem /inheritance:d

REM Delete "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users" from having any rights
icacls mykeypair.pem /remove "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users"

REM Delete "BUILTIN\Users" from having any rights
icacls mykeypair.pem /remove "BUILTIN\Users"

REM Grant Read-Only rights to me
icacls mykeypair.pem /GRANT:R "%USERNAME%:(R)"
```

Comment: Could someone tell me the exact wording I needto put into the ~/.ssh/config file to keep the privatekeypair there permanent? Merci

Comment: @aerioeus assuming this is correct, copy that key to somewhere in the Linux filesystem -- not under /mnt/c but, say, in your home directory, and see if you get a different result.

Comment: that worked, thanks. created a directory ~/.ec2 and copied the mykeypair.pem there. after that I inserted the nfo into ~/.ssh/config. Now I can use ```ssh -A``` merci A

Answer (score 0):

Below are some possible reasons,

1. Check permission of your private key and set it's permission to 600.
2. Use correct private key.
3. Use correct username or add your user in your config like this `User vikas`

Hope this would help.

Comment: my config looks like this:

```Host jumphost
 3    HostName 52.17.172.45
 4    User ubuntu
 5    IdentityFile /mnt/c/Users/xxx/AWS/ecs_key.pem
 6    ProxyCommand none
```
I have applied chmod 400 to the keypair file as aws suggests. still getting the error...

when i connect directly with ssh-i everything works...

Comment: @aerioeus can you try login using this command `ssh -i /mnt/c/Users/xxx/AWS/mykeypair.pem ubuntu@52.17.172.45` and check if it is working fine or not ?